# Magento EE 1.14.1 RWD not displaying Rotating banner widget

Tags: magento-enterprise, rwd-theme, widgets, enterprise-1.14

I'm testing Magento EE 1.14.1 using the RWD theme (rwd/default) and have come across the following problem.

- I've created a very simple banner which is just plain text. It is not
  associated with a promotion or a segment.
- To preview I've inserted the banner into a standard CMS page using
  the insert widget tool and then the rotating banner method (set
  to show all banners at once). I've assigned the banner to this.
- Caching is turned off so no need to flush.
- When I go to view the page on the frontend the banner is not displayed.
- If I change the theme back to the original enterprise/default and view the page the banner displays.

I've also tried viewing the banner using the widget with a layout position (multiple layout positions) but to no avail.

Is anyone aware of anything I am doing wrong? Has anyone else come across this problem or able to replicate it. I've tried on two instances of EE and the problem happens on both.

Is this a bug or an error on my part? and if anyone has a solution I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you use the `rwd/default` template, that you have to make sure that it's parent is enterprise.

You can add/change a file `etc/theme.xml` to `rwd/default` with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>enterprise/default</parent>
</theme>
```

That way, Magento's lookup is changed from

- rwd/theme
- rwd/default
- base/default

to

- rwd/theme
- rwd/default
- enterprise/default
- base/default

There's also a `rwd/enterprise` so be sure to set it correctly in the Magento backend.